# How do I remove the "Installed x object(x) from y fixture(s)" report from django test?

Tags: django, testing, fixtures, verbosity

I am using fixtures during my django tests as they are proving to be quite useful

```
def some_test(self):
    ...
    call_command('loaddata', 'path/to/fixture.json')
    ...
    self.assertTrue(...)
```

And when I run my tests, they all pass:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
......................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 40 tests in 0.104s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

However, the "Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)" is starting to annoy me.

Is there a way to reduce the verbosity of the command? So then it could look like:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 40 tests in 0.104s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Which is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call_command('loaddata', '-v', '0', 'path/to/fixture.json')
```

This will set the verbosity to 0, meaning that nothing will be reported unless something goes terribly wrong.